# Issues with a newsletter signup api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sendgrid

The form I created is intended to send a user inputted email to my Sendgrid contacts list. It successfully does this but there are a couple of issues:

1. The page sticks on loading when submitted
2. The frontend logic isn't working as I want it to hide the input and display text

Here is the backend code:

```
app.post('/subscribe', (req, res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;
    const options = {
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts',
        headers:
        {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            authorization: 'Bearer **MYSECRETKEY**'
        },
        body:
        {
            list_ids: ['**MYSECRETID**'],
            contacts:
                [{
                    email: email,
                }]
        },
        json: true
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) { 
            throw new Error(error);
        } else {
            res.status(200);
        }
    });
})
```

Here is the form

```
<div id="signup">
                <form action="/subscribe" method="POST" novalidate class="validated-form">
                    <label class="form-label" for="signup">Signup to receive the latest tips & trends</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="youremail@email.com" required>
                    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="button" id="cta">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="success" class="inner-form">
                <h2 class="text-center">Thank you!</h2>
            </div>
```

Here is the frontend Javascript

```
<script>

    let cta = document.getElementById('cta');
    let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    let error = document.getElementById('error');
    let success = document.getElementById('success');
    let signup = document.getElementById('signup');

    cta.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

        if (this.email.value == null || this.email.value == "") {
            error.classList.add('errorAnim');
        } else {
            let fetchData = {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({ email: this.email.value }),
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
            }

            fetch('/subscribe', fetchData)
                .then(res => {
                    if (res.ok) {
                        signup.classList.add('fadeout');
                        success.classList.add('fadein');
                    } else {
                        error.classList.add('errorAnim');
                    }
                })
        }
    })

    (function () {
    'use strict'

    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.validated-form')

    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    Array.from(forms)
        .forEach(function (form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    event.stopPropagation()
                }

                form.classList.add('was-validated')
            }, false)
        })
})()

</script>
```

Many thanks for you help! I'm still learning

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

If your server-side is stuck loading, then perhaps there is an error returning from the API and you are not responding to the request. Try adding a response in the error clause:

```js
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) { 
            throw new Error(error);
            res.status(500).send(error.message);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send();
        }
    });
```

In your front-end code you refer to `this.email` however I don't believe that `this.email` is set in this context. You do create an `email` variable earlier (`let email = document.getElementById('email').value;`) but this is the value of the email field when the code runs on page load, not when the form is submitted. So, I would change the variable to just get the element and then use the `email` variable to look up the value at the time of sending.

It is also better to listen to the submit event of the form rather than a click event of a button in the form. This allows you to capture form submissions from pressing return within a form field rather than solely relying on a click on a button. Then, when you do this you need to prevent the default form submission behaviour. You can do this with `event.preventDefault()`.

Let's update the HTML to add an id to the form so that we can select it later:

```html
<div id="signup">
  <form action="/subscribe" method="POST" novalidate class="validated-form" id="signup-form">
    <label class="form-label" for="signup">Signup to receive the latest tips & trends</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="youremail@email.com" required>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="button" id="cta">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="success" class="inner-form">
  <h2 class="text-center">Thank you!</h2>
</div>
```

```js
    let form = document.getElementById('signup-form');
    let email = document.getElementById('email');
    let error = document.getElementById('error');
    let success = document.getElementById('success');
    let signup = document.getElementById('signup');

    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (email.value == null || email.value == "") {
            error.classList.add('errorAnim');
        } else {
            let fetchData = {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({ email: email.value }),
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
            }

            fetch('/subscribe', fetchData)
                .then(res => {
                    if (res.ok) {
                        signup.classList.add('fadeout');
                        success.classList.add('fadein');
                    } else {
                        error.classList.add('errorAnim');
                    }
                })
        }
    })
```

Let me know if either of those things helps.

Comment: It seems to work but I have another issue (forgive me as I am new-ish) - it redirects to /subscribe on a blank page but I want it to stay on this page and display the frontend logic (i.e. add the #success span of Success! to replace the form)

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. What you want to do is listen to the submit event on the form, instead of the click even on the button, and then call on `event.preventDefault()` to stop it submitting for real. There is more explanation and example code in my updated answer.